# Html and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 3 drop down lists which have to come one after another.

```
<select ng-model="vm.filter.location">
  <option value="Andhra Pradesh" ng-if="vm.isDistrict && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage">All Districts</option>
  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.geoGraphList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isDistrict && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage">{{ location }}</option>
  <option ng-if="vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage && !vm.isDistrict" selected disabled>All Mandals</option>
  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.mandalList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage && !vm.isDistrict">{{ location }}</option>
  <option ng-if="vm.isVillage && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isDistrict" selected disabled>All Villages</option>
  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.villageList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isVillage && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isDistrict">{{ location }}</option>
</select>
```

First list contains list of districts , in which if I select a district and click submit , i am getting list of mandals and on selecting a mandal i am getting list of villages.

In first list i am getting the default option as "ALL DISTRICTS" but in other lists i am not able to get the default option on the list.
I even added the "selected disabled" in  tag.
A little help would be appreciated?

Comment: This is the beginning of the list.

<select ng-model="vm.filter.location">
                                  <option value="Andhra Pradesh" ng-if="vm.isDistrict && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage">All Districts</option>
                                  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.geoGraphList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isDistrict && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage">{{ location }}</option>

Comment: you can only select one `option`, unless you've set the `multiple` attribute. Looks like you'll want to split them in three `select` boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `disabled` tag to select option. Select menu will not select disabled option by default as browser considered it as unusable so it is not possible to select it.
You can use `ng-disabled` to make option enable/disable.

```
<select ng-model="vm.filter.location">
  <option value="Andhra Pradesh" ng-if="vm.isDistrict && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage">All Districts</option>
  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.geoGraphList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isDistrict && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage">{{ location }}</option>
  <option ng-if="vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage && !vm.isDistrict" selected ng-disabled="vm.isVillage || vm.isDistrict">All Mandals</option>
  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.mandalList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isMandal && !vm.isVillage && !vm.isDistrict">{{ location }}</option>
  <option ng-if="vm.isVillage && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isDistrict" selected ng-disabled="vm.isMandal || vm.isDistrict">All Villages</option>
  <option ng-repeat="location in vm.villageList" value="{{location}}" ng-if="vm.isVillage && !vm.isMandal && !vm.isDistrict">{{ location }}</option>
</select>
```

Or else you can manage it within controller
Or you can refer cascading dropdown demo
http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1189/angularjs-cascading-dropdown-select-with-demo